# Android Gallery like app

Tags: android

I want to implement app like Gallery in android.

The images captured from camera/gallery must be displayed in thumbnails and whenever i click on thumbnail image should display the full image like in built Gallery app in android devices.

Please help me..

Answer (score 0):

Import the images selected into a gallery, it will prepare thumbnails automatically.
Take another activity with imageview and a button to display selected thumbnail in full screen, launch this activity when you click any item in gallery. This is available in below example.

[Gallery-ImageView Example](http://www.androidpeople.com/android-gallery-imageview-example)

Coming to **Delete** button, you have to write action for this button, onClick() method of button's View.onClickListener interface. Please see android developers website to know more about file deletion.

I think you understood.

Comment: I want to implement in-built gallery like app in my application

Comment: is my answer 50% correct to your question regarding gallery part ? i think you need how to capture image from camera, correct ?

Comment: Yes, i know how to capture image from camera / gallery. But whatever the images selected must be displayed in thumbnails and whenever i select one of the thumbnail image, it should be display in fullview with delete button like we see in built-in gallery.